# Firebase Authentication "A value of type 'AuthResult' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'FirebaseUser'"

Tags: firebase-authentication

There is a tutorial series on Flutter & Firebase authentication. When I've cloned the project and run, the following error was dropped in auth.dart and in login_page.dart. How could I fix this please?

> A value of type 'AuthResult'  can't be assigned to a variable of type 'FirebaseUser'

Code is given below:

```
 class Auth implements BaseAuth {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;


  Future<String> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    return user.uid;
  }
  Future<String> createUser(String email, String password) async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    return user.uid;
  }
```

and  error in login method 'signInWithEmailAndPassword' isn't defined for the class 'BaseAuth'.
Code is given below:

```
 Future<void> validateAndSubmit() async {
    if (validateAndSave()) {
      try {
        final BaseAuth auth = AuthProvider.of(context).auth;
        if (_formType == FormType.login) {
          final String userId = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password);
          print('Signed in: $userId');
        } else {
          final String userId = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password);
          print('Registered user: $userId');
        }
        widget.onSignedIn();
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error: $e');
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently there have been updates on the package firebase_auth now the methods return a `Future<AuthResult>`. If you want your `FirebaseUser` you need to get the `AuthResult.user`.
Something like this should work for you :

```
FirebaseUser user = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)).user;
```